# Connecting multiple macros within a single sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to code date change if a cell is modified plus integrate a ALL CAPS text. I have the date change working but cant seem to figure out what I'm missing to get the ALL CAPS working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Fill in Date.
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("J:J"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 20
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
        Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
        Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
    Else
        Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
    End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
Else If
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
' Loop to cycle through each cell in the specified range.
For Each x In Range("A10:D1000,G10:J1000,T10:T1000")
  ' Change the text in the range to uppercase letters.
  x.Value = UCase(x.Value)
Next
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what error are you getting and where?  The `Else If` is orphaned outside the If.  Remove it.

Comment: @ScottCraner The error is Expected: expression at `Else If` at line 20.

Comment: So do you want the last part to fire only when the data is changed outside column J, or always?

Comment: No i would always want it to fire.

Comment: Then delete the `Else If`

Comment: I can believe it was that simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the cells inside the range.

```
For Each cell In Range("A10:D1000,G10:J1000,T10:T1000").Cells
  ' Change the text in the range to uppercase letters.
  cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
Next
```